# basic math problem relating to log thought my answer is not matching with the alternative

Tags: logarithms

> $1/2 \log c = 0.915$. Calculate $c$.

It is a basic math problem but my answers are not matching with the alternatives.

1. $1/2 \log c= c^{1/2}$
2. $ c^{1/2}= 0.915$
3. $c = 0.915 \times 0.915=0.83448$

but the answers is $0.15$.

Comment: use Tex to typeset your question

Answer (score 1):

You went from $\log(c^{1/2})=0.915$ to $c^{1/2}=0.915$. That is not a valid transition.

$$
\frac12\log c=0.915\\
\log(c^{1/2})=0.915\\
c^{1/2}=10^{0.915}=8.22\\
c=8.22^2=67.6
$$

Comment: im still stuck. How do i do it? thanks.

Comment: @JamesGeorge Is your logarithm base ten or base $e$?

Comment: the log has base 10.

Comment: @JamesGeorge I added a solution to my answer. As you can see, $0.15$ is not the correct answer at all. You could've seen that just by calculating $1/2\log(0.15)=-0.41$.